# Which TAR to install - IA-64 or X86 64bit?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I just installed 64bit Ubuntu Server 10.04. Server is Dell PowerEdge R710 with Intel Xeon 5506 Quad Core CPU. I am trying to install MySQL server 5.5 now, just wondering which TAR file I should pick - IA-64 or X86 64-bit? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you installing MySQL from a *tar* file? Ubuntu has prepackaged MySQL binaries.

Comment: For MySQL 5.1 - not for MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X86 64-bit

That is unless you have an Itanium mainframe system (that's the ia64 architecture).

Comment: Not exactly "mainframe." I've got two Itanium systems, one is 4U the other is 1U. Got them off eBay.